# Ruby Rbox Rye undefined method for rbox object comparrison

Tags: ruby

I'm using rbox rye gem to run some tests to verify I can ping/connect to a host and then verify that certain directories/files exist on a host and then that a specific file is being uploaded to a host.

Most of the functionality is complete but one thing is missing and that is to verify I can actually connect to the host.

I use the following method to make the host connection.
The return value of the method is a connection string object (username@rye_10.16.11.100)

```
def connection()
  con = Rye::Box.new("#{@host}")
  con
end
```

Later in the code I want to validate that the connection succeeded:

```
if ((file.connection()) == #{HOST})
  puts "Connected to Host"
else
  puts "Not able to connect to Host"
end
```

However, the test fails with the following error:

```
gems/rye-0.9.12/lib/rye/box.rb:408:in `==': undefined method `host' for 0:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
from test_rye.rb:99:in `<main>'
```

I assume that the comparrisson operator is not valid to test for the returned rbox host object.
Is there a way that I can perform that comparrisson?

Thanks

Comment: ... Why are you doing `"#{@host}"`?

Comment: I'm passing the host name via the ruby class initialize method:                                                                     def initialize(host, user, password, backup, base_dir )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your @host variable is holding a num instead of a hostname. Looking at the source code of Rye::Box, you can see that the comparison method is comparing the hostname that you initialised it with: https://github.com/delano/rye/blob/2d9ffd6d18688cc85ec1a004e35d12d8909b5ed6/lib/rye/box.rb#L408

I would take the following steps:

- Add a debugger before `con = Rye::Box.new("#{@host}")` to check that the @host variable is actually a string.
- If it is, add a debugger before `if ((file.connection()) == #{HOST})` to see what file.connection returns.

As a side note, you should change #{HOST} to @host in that last statement; that's the correct way to access the instance variable.

Hopefully that'll shed some clarity to the problem!

Comment: I used debugger statements inside the connection method and also in the calling class.

Comment: @Hunar           def connection()
    con = Rye::Box.new("#{@host}")
    puts "Inside Connect Method"
    puts "Connection String: #{con}”
end

puts file.connection()

In both cases a connection string object is printed: 
    user_name@rye_10.10.10.100

Also, I used #{HOST} because in the calling class I have the host variable declared as HOST = 10.10.10.100